# apply() method: Normalize the first column by the sum of the second

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm having trouble understanding how a function works:

```
""" the apply() method lets you apply an arbitrary function to the group 
result. The function take a DataFrame and returns a Pandas object (a df or 
series) or a scalar.
For example: normalize the first column by the sum of the second"""

def norm_by_data2(x):
    # x is a DataFrame of group values
    x['data1'] /= x['data2'].sum()
    return x
print (df); print (df.groupby('key').apply(norm_by_data2))
```

(Excerpt from: "Python Data Science Handbook", Jake VanderPlas pp. 167)

Returns this:

```
key  data1  data2
0   A      0      5
1   B      1      0
2   C      2      3
3   A      3      3
4   B      4      7
5   C      5      9
key     data1  data2
0   A  0.000000      5
1   B  0.142857      0
2   C  0.166667      3
3   A  0.375000      3
4   B  0.571429      7
5   C  0.416667      9
```

For me, the best way to understand how this works is by manually calculating the values.

Can someone explain how to manually arrive to the second value of the column 'data1': 0.142857

It's 1/7? but where do this values come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it!!

The sum of column B for each group is:

```
A: 5 + 3 =  8
B: 0 + 7 =  7
C: 3 + 9 = 12
```

For example, to arrive to 0.142857, divide 1 in the sum of group B (it's 7) : 1/7 = 0.142857

Comment: if you just solve your own question, please accept your own answer so people can understand that it's no longer active

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I get 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'. I will try again in 2 days.